# jCarouselLite and fancybox popup

Tags: javascript, jquery, fancybox, jcarousellite

I am using jCarouselLite and fancybox together, please see this link

http://travianstation.com/index.html

script: http://travianstation.com/scripts/script.js

If you click on "Gallery" without scrolling down, Gallery will poup on correct positions but if scroll down and then click on Gallery they are not in center of windows and second images row come above the large image.

Kindly can someone guide me how to fix this issue. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Inside your [script.js](http://travianstation.com/scripts/script.js) file you have this piece of code

```
$().ready(function() {
 var $scrollingDiv = $("#fancybox-contentB");
 var $scrollingDivB = $("#fancybox-content");
 $(window).scroll(function(){                   
   $scrollingDiv.stop().animate({"marginTop": ($(window).scrollTop() + 30) + "px"}, "slow");            
   $scrollingDivB.stop().animate({"marginTop": ($(window).scrollTop() + 30) + "px"}, "slow");           
 });
});
```

that I suspect is adding dynamically *30px* to the `marginTop` of the `#fancybox-content` for each little inch you scroll down the window, pushing it literally down out of the screen (try to scroll down continuously the window while fancybox is opened to see the effect.)

What is the idea of having this function?

Comment: Thanks for ur reply, I am using that function to scroll both boxes when page is scrolling, so until user dont click on close button, it will animate up/down with mouse. if you open that link and click on gallery it will work perfect, even moving good with scrolling but gallery is not in middle of page if i open gallery after scrolling down .

Comment: Fancybox v1.3.x has the option `centerOnScroll` that produces the same effect. Just add `"centerOnScroll": true` to your fancybox script.

Comment: Thanks I have added and modified some css and works perfectly now :)